# Como selecionar o primeiro elemento do xml

Tags: php, xml

Tenho o seguinte xml:

```
<SONG>
<PLAYEDAT>1487812025</PLAYEDAT>
<TITLE>John Legend - Love Me Now</TITLE>
<METADATA>
<TIT2>John Legend - Love Me Now</TIT2>
</METADATA>
</SONG>
<SONG>
<PLAYEDAT>1487811800</PLAYEDAT>
<TITLE>Ed Sheeran - Sing</TITLE>
<METADATA>
<TIT2>Ed Sheeran - Sing</TIT2>
</METADATA>
</SONG>
<SONG>
<PLAYEDAT>1487811572</PLAYEDAT>
<TITLE>Maroon 5 - Animals</TITLE>
<METADATA>
<TIT2>Maroon 5 - Animals</TIT2>
</METADATA>
</SONG>
```

E o seguinte php:

```
foreach ($songs->SONGHISTORY->SONG as $song){
    $exp = explode(' - ', $song->TITLE);
    $json[] = array(
        'data' => $song->PLAYEDAT,
        'artista' => $exp[0],
        'musica' => $exp[1],
        'itunes' => $song->TITLE
    );
}
```

Porém, tenho um problema, não consigo selecionar um **SONG** específico, gostaria de selecionar apenas o primeiro **SONG**, *como é possível fazer isso?*

Comment: Já tentou, ao invés de iterar sobre a lista, executar o mesmo código só em `$songs->SONGHISTORY->SONG[0]`?

Comment: Sim, não retorna nenhum valor.

Comment: Mas pelo `foreach` funciona?

Comment: Não, não funciona de nenhum jeito.

Comment: Então edite sua pergunta, coloque o código inteiro e indique qual é o erro que está dando.

Comment: Opa, consegui amigo, usei json e consegui manipular o xml, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como citado por @humberto-tecnoboy, há uma falha no seu XML, pois ele não possui um elemento root:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SONGS>
    <SONG>
        <PLAYEDAT>1487812025</PLAYEDAT>
        <TITLE>John Legend - Love Me Now</TITLE>
        <METADATA>
            <TIT2>John Legend - Love Me Now</TIT2>
        </METADATA>
    </SONG>
    <SONG>
        <PLAYEDAT>1487811800</PLAYEDAT>
        <TITLE>Ed Sheeran - Sing</TITLE>
        <METADATA>
            <TIT2>Ed Sheeran - Sing</TIT2>
        </METADATA>
    </SONG>
    <SONG>
        <PLAYEDAT>1487811572</PLAYEDAT>
        <TITLE>Maroon 5 - Animals</TITLE>
        <METADATA>
            <TIT2>Maroon 5 - Animals</TIT2>
        </METADATA>
    </SONG>
</SONGS>`

A partir daqui (considerando que o XML já possui uma estrutura válida) basta carregar o arquivo em um objeto **DOMDocument**, certificando-se que o conteúdo de tabulações, espaços e outras formações apenas visuais sejam ignoradas atribuindo ao atributo *preserveWhiteSpace* o valor **false**, e se utilizar da captura do conjunto de tags como o nome que se esta buscando através do método *getElementsByTagName*, com isso, acesse o primeiro *item* deste conjunto:

> <?php
>   $xml = new DOMDocument();
>   $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
>  
>   $xml->load('./song.xml');
>
> echo ''
>   ,  $xml->getElementsByTagName('SONG')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('PLAYEDAT')->item(0)->nodeValue
>   ,  "\n"
>   ,  $xml->getElementsByTagName('SONG')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('TITLE')->item(0)->nodeValue
>   ,  "\n"
>   ,  $xml->getElementsByTagName('SONG')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('METADATA')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('TIT2')->item(0)->nodeValue
>   ,  "\n"
>   ;

Obs: o nó TIT2 poderia ter sido obtido apelas buscando o nodeValue de seu nó superior (METADATA) já que ele é o único nó filho, mas o fiz desta forma apenas para seguir o padrão de buscar a primeira ocorrência da busca por um nó a partir do nome da tag

Answer (score 1):

O XML precisa ser modificado:

```
$PLAYLIST=
"<PLAYLIST>
    <SONG>
        <PLAYEDAT>1487812025</PLAYEDAT>
        <TITLE>John Legend - Love Me Now</TITLE>
        <METADATA>
            <TIT2>John Legend - Love Me Now</TIT2>
        </METADATA>
    </SONG>
    <SONG>
        <PLAYEDAT>1487811800</PLAYEDAT>
        <TITLE>Ed Sheeran - Sing</TITLE>
        <METADATA>
            <TIT2>Ed Sheeran - Sing</TIT2>
        </METADATA>
    </SONG>
    <SONG>
        <PLAYEDAT>1487811572</PLAYEDAT>
        <TITLE>Maroon 5 - Animals</TITLE>
        <METADATA>
            <TIT2>Maroon 5 - Animals</TIT2>
        </METADATA>
    </SONG>
</PLAYLIST>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($PLAYLIST);

foreach($xml->SONG as $song)
{
    echo "<pre>".print_r($song, true)."</pre>";
}
```